# Unable to read data with selenium webdriver from ag-grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, text-extraction, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to automate an application where there are several services running and are displayed in ag grid in Angular. Problem statement is that I am not able to read data from the same.

Can anyone help? I need to read service name from each row and its respective status from other column.

I tried to iterate through each row  and read data from there using for loop. I was expecting it to extract data from table but did not even detected the grid.

Comment: Welcome, as its currently written there is no specific question to answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask